# Upload multiple files with parameters in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

My view model:

```
public class FileInfo
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "TitleErrorMessage", MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "DesErrorMessage", MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```

The following is _UploadForm partial view file:

```html
@model SessionStateTest.Models.FileInfo

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Title</label>
    <input class="form-control" asp-for="Title" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Description</label>
    <input class="form-control" asp-for="Description" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label></label>
    <input type="file" asp-for="File" />
</div>
```

That is used in another View with this code:

```html
<form asp-action="AddUploadForm" asp-controller="Home" method="Post">
    <input type="submit" value="Add another file" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" />
</form>
<form asp-action="Upload" asp-controller="Home" method="Post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    @foreach (var item in Model.Upload)
    {
        @(await Html.PartialAsync("_UploadForm", item))
    }

    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Basically `AddUploadForm` action adds a new view model of type `FileInfo` to `Model.Upload` which is my main view model. 
The problem is that the list `List<FileInfo> vm` in `Upload` action below is totally empty:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Upload(List<FileInfo> vm)
{
    .... some other logic 
    return View();
}
```

I don't want to use `multiple` attribute because I would like to force user to provide a title and description for every file.

Any help is kindly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach with using `_UploadForm` generates the following html (let's focus on `input`'s only since this is the most important part)

```
<input class="form-control" name="Title" />
<input class="form-control" name="Description" />
<input type="file" name="File" />

...
<input class="form-control" name="Title" />
<input class="form-control" name="Description" />
<input type="file" name="File" />

... and so on
```

So `name` attributes contains only `FileInfo` model's properties names without indexes and this is only suitable for the case when your controller expects single model

```
public IActionResult Upload(FileInfo vm)
```

And in order to make your html work with your current controller with list of models

```
public IActionResult Upload(List<FileInfo> vm)
```

It should look like this

```
<!-- version 1 -->
<input class="form-control" name="[0].Title" />
<input class="form-control" name="[0].Description" />
<input type="file" name="[0].File" />

...
<input class="form-control" name="[1].Title" />
<input class="form-control" name="[1].Description" />
<input type="file" name="[1].File" />

... and so on
```

Or

```
<!-- version 2 -->
<!-- the name before index must match parameter name in controller -->
<input class="form-control" name="vm[0].Title" />
<input class="form-control" name="vm[0].Description" />
<input type="file" name="vm[0].File" />

...
<input class="form-control" name="[1].Title" />
<input class="form-control" name="[1].Description" />
<input type="file" name="vm[1].File" />

... and so on
```

This is possible to accomplish using tag helpers and partial view in slightly different way. All you need to do is turn partial view's model to list and update `asp-for` expressions.

**_UploadForm.cshtml**

```
@model List<SessionStateTest.Models.FileInfo>

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Title</label>
        <input class="form-control" asp-for="@Model[i].Title" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Description</label>
        <input class="form-control" asp-for="@Model[i].Description" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label></label>
        <input type="file" asp-for="@Model[i].File" />
    </div>
}
```

**View**

```
<form asp-action="Upload" asp-controller="Home" method="Post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    @await Html.PartialAsync("_UploadForm", Model.Upload)

    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" />
    </div>
</form>
```

It will generate html like in *version 1*.

Comment: Thank you! that solved the problem. But may I ask why it didn't work when I tried `name="Title[]"`? As far as I know this should work or did I miss something?

Comment: @Niroda I believe this works for PHP but not for ASP.NET :)