# how to send array to API which contains image and other data in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui

When I am passing a single object like below then it is working as per below image

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromForm] MyModel Details)
{
}
```

[image]

but when I am passing the **List** of the object to API then it is not working. option to upload a file is not visible. and if I entered any values in the array then also I am getting count 0 for details.

```
 [HttpPost]
 public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromForm] List<MyModel> Details)
 {}
```

[image]

I want to pass the List of images and descriptions to API. How can I achieve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54724058/upload-multiple-files-with-parameters-in-asp-net-core

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need custom model binding for the list model . Here is a similar demo:

**custom model binding code:**

```cs
    public class MetadataValueModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            if (bindingContext == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
    
            var values = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
    
            if (values.Length == 0)
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };
    
            var deserialized = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(values.FirstValue, bindingContext.ModelType, options);
    
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(deserialized);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

**Add the model binder to the model class:**

```cs
    public class MasterDTO
    {
        public string Comments { get; set; }
        public IFormFile File { get; set; }        
        public List<DetailDTO> Details { get; set; }
    
        public MasterDTO()
        {
            this.Details = new List<DetailDTO>();
        }
    }
    
    [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(MetadataValueModelBinder))]
    public class DetailDTO
    {
        public Int64 ElementId { get; set; }
    
        public double LowerLimit { get; set; }
    
        public double HigherLimit { get; set; }
    
        public string Status { get; set; }
    
        public string UserAuthorization { get; set; }
    
        public DateTime? AutorizationDate { get; set; }
    }
```

**controller/action**

```cs
            [HttpPost]
            public async Task<IActionResult> CreateProjectLimit([FromForm] MasterDTO masterDto)
            {
                //...
    
                return Ok();
            }
```

[image]
[image]

**You can just use postman to pass the list of images and Descriptions to API**

[image]
[image]

Comment: I want to pass an array of images and descriptions to API. Each array element will have image and description. from your approach, we can send only one image at a time.

Comment: Hi,I have edited my answer . You can just use postman to pass the list of images and Descriptions to API

Answer (score 0):

Below is the right answer. we can use Postman to pass images in the array as shown below.

[image]